# Android Connection Problem -Ubuntu

Tags: usb, android, connection, mtp

When I connect my android in ubuntu device through usb, the android device is not showing up, i tried adb devices i changed to mtp transfer, i changed 51-android.rules and 69-mtp.rules accordingly but nothing worked, i need to use Android File Transfer app in ubuntu to work which is frustrating to work with.

Answer (score 0):

just use, this command if you face a similar issue,

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends;
```